# Javascript Object: Object unable to parse into JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using cucumber js to transform my table `hash` into JSON using `JSON.parse(hash)`. However it's giving me

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
```

my hash looks like this:

```
  { id: '545905cad7cc1da6af000016',
    title: 'Are you hosting Thanksgiving dinner?',
    gender: 'Female',
    min_age: '20',
    max_age: '75',
    brand_action_group_name: 'Engagement Poll',
    choices: '[{\'53152604fa0c861e72000008\': \'Yes – it is my favorite!\'}, {\'53152604fa0c861e72000008\': \'No, too much work.\'}]' }
```

I tried pasting it into the console to debug but it is giving me a weird error??

```
{ id:'53152604fa0c861e72000006', blah:"fsd"}
> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

What is wrong with my object? I don't get it...

Comment: You do not have (valid) JSON, but a JavaScript object. There are some differences ...

Comment: `JSON.parse()` converts **from** JSON, not **to** JSON. And you get the syntax error because a JavaScript object literal alone is not a valid statement.

Answer (score 4):

JSON.parse() is Javascript to JSON.

JSON to Javasccript is JSON.stringify();

Comment: Pedantry: `parse` parses a valid JSON string to a JavaScript object and `stringify` does the opposite. *Javascript to JSON* or *JSON to Javascript* is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check your JSON string on [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/)
I've tried, and seems to be wrong, it says:

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    id: '545905cad7cc1da
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

Hope this helps!